# Is __destruct() called when the same object has another instance?

Tags: php, oop

This is pretty short question. Is __destruct called whenever i instantiate the same object again? (in PHP)

Comment: An object can't have an instance, only classes can have instances. Instances are defined as a realized variation of a class'es blueprint.

Comment: it would have taken 10 seconds to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty short and obvious answer: no.
Only when an object instance gets *destroyed*.

Of course:

```
$foo = new Bar;
$foo = new Bar;
```

Here the instance assigned to `$foo` *is* being destroyed, because `$foo` is being overwritten; regardless of what it is being overwritten with.

Comment: ISTM you should say “*might be* destroyed *later*”.  It is garbage collection that causes `__destruct()` to be called.  In this case, the method is called twice, one time per object. The first time it is called on the first object when the last reference to the first object is deleted per the second assignment. The second time it is called for the second object just before the program ends, as the `$foo` variable is deleted and the reference it holds to the second object is removed.